# Elasticsearch relevance how to achieve the best?

Tags: elasticsearch

I used `Elasticsearch` to develop a project

The project needs to use the packet aggregation and search, ES function is very easy to use, to meet all my needs, but I feel confused is the relevance of ES

For example, I have these indexes:

```
Cd54 prodoct
Cd59 product
Cd58 product
Cd50 product
Cd5 product
Cd 5 product
Cd55 prodcut
Cd55 other product
Thcd5 prodcut
```

Search Keyword: cd5

The sort I want is:

```
Cd5 product
Cd55 product
Cd55 other product
Thcd5 product
Cd50 product
...
```

And cd 5 product is not displayed

I made the following strategy:

Set a custom filter auto_ngram_filter

```
Open nGram, min_gram = 1, max_gram = 20, token_chars = [ "post", "digit", "punctuation", "symbol", "whitespace"]
```

And customize an analyzer

```
type = custom, filter = [ "standard", "lowercase", "filter auto_ngram_filter"]
```

Mapping settings are as follows:

```
Index_options = offsets,
Similarity = bm25
Analyzer = my_analyzer,
Include_in_all = true,
Term_vector = with_positions_offsets_payloads
```

The actual _score sort is:

```
Cd58 product
Cd59 product
Cd54 product
Cd50 product
Cd55 product
Cd55 other product
Cd5 product
Thcd5 product
```

I do not understand is that if calculated value is an incorrect value, because `docfreq = 1, doccount = 1`. This is the majority of the data if calculation terms, but the part is indeed `docfreq = 2, doccount = 2` ? How to get these results?

According to the ES official documents, the shorter the word the higher the weight, but in fact it is not, and the perfect match and did not get a high score.

How can I set up to achieve my goal? Tried many methods and can not solve the problem, I need your help, if you know how to solve this problem, please tell me, thank you very much!